# Strongest symmetric algorithm in 2022

Tags: aes, file-encryption

I'm curious about the best encryption algorithm for encrypting my files in 2022? I thought it was a good solution to encrypt my private key with AES-256 but I decided to ask here and choose better algorithm.

If the answer is still AES, which mode should I use? I heard about GCM and CBC modes but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: AES-256-GCM is still perfectly fine to use.

Comment: You can't simply put all the algorithms on a linear scale; it depends on your requirements and threats you want to address.

Comment: Relevant post: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184305/why-would-i-ever-use-aes-256-cbc-if-aes-256-gcm-is-more-secure?rq=1

Comment: This is easy to look up: https://www.google.com/search?q=Strongest+symmetric+algorithm+in+2022 Please make sure that you have looked up your question before asking here. And you can't just conclude that one algorithm is "strongest". Each have different strengths based on your requirements and constraints.